# Javascript placement using grid on site:

Tags: javascript, css, css-grid

Hello I have several javascript files, I want to put them on the site but place them using grid in css.
I'll share the code with you, I do not understand:
Where do I need to write columns and rows so that after I add columns and rows to the .box-1 class it will change its position?

I have several more javascript files for which I want to change the position, my question, is it advisable to leave each javascript file separately and link it to HTML or is it recommended to merge all the javascript files into one file and then link to HTML?
Thanks.

```js
const panels = document.querySelectorAll('.panel')

panels.forEach(panel => {
  panel.addEventListener('click', () => {
    removeActiveClasses()
    panel.classList.add('active')
  })
})

function removeActiveClasses() {
  panels.forEach(panel => {
    panel.classList.remove('active')
  })
}
```

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Muli&display=swap');
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  font-family: 'Muli', sans-serif;
  display: grid;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  height: 100vh;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 0;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr;
}

.box-1 {
  display: flex;
  width: 30vw;
  height: auto;
  flex-direction: row;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  width: 90vw;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr;
}

.box-1 {
  grid-column: 3/4;
  grid-row: 2/3;
}

.panel {
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  height: 80vh;
  border-radius: 50px;
  color: #fff;
  cursor: pointer;
  flex: 0.5;
  margin: 10px;
  position: relative;
  -webkit-transition: all 700ms ease-in;
}

.panel h3 {
  font-size: 24px;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 20px;
  left: 20px;
  margin: 0;
  opacity: 0;
}

.panel.active {
  flex: 5;
}

.panel.active h3 {
  opacity: 1;
  transition: opacity 0.3s ease-in 0.4s;
}

@media (max-width: 480px) {
  .container {
    width: 100vw;
  }
  .panel:nth-of-type(4),
  .panel:nth-of-type(5) {
    display: none;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="box 1">

  <div class="container">
    <div class="panel active" style="background-image: url('https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1558979158-65a1eaa08691?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1350&q=80')">
      <h3>Explore The World</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="panel" style="background-image: url('https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1572276596237-5db2c3e16c5d?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1350&q=80')">
      <h3>Wild Forest</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="panel" style="background-image: url('https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1507525428034-b723cf961d3e?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1353&q=80')">
      <h3>Sunny Beach</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="panel" style="background-image: url('https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1551009175-8a68da93d5f9?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1351&q=80')">
      <h3>City on Winter</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="panel" style="background-image: url('https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1549880338-65ddcdfd017b?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1350&q=80')">
      <h3>Mountains - Clouds</h3>
    </div>

  </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I succeeded:
I added 2 queues so that they could take up space and the JavaScript file I reduced its width-

```
enter code here @import 

url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Muli&display=swap');

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}



body {
  font-family: 'Muli', sans-serif;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  height: 100vh;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 0;
   display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr; 
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  width: 30vw;
 justify-items: center;
 grid-column: 2/3;
}

.card{
  grid-column: 1/2;
  width: 80vh;
  margin: 30px;
}
.card2{
  grid-column: 3/4;
  width: 80vh;
  margin: 30px;
}

.panel {
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  height: 30vh;
  border-radius: 50px;
  color: #fff;
  cursor: pointer;
  flex: 0.5;
  margin: 10px;
  position: relative;
  -webkit-transition: all 700ms ease-in;
  grid-column: 3/4;
  width: 30vh;
}

.panel h3 {
  font-size: 24px;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 20px;
  left: 20px;
  margin: 0;
  opacity: 0;
  
}

.panel.active {
  flex: 5;
}

.panel.active h3 {
  opacity: 1;
  transition: opacity 0.3s ease-in 0.4s;
}

@media (max-width: 480px) {
  .container {
    width: 100vw;
  }

  .panel:nth-of-type(4),
  .panel:nth-of-type(5) {
    display: none;
  }
}
```

Comment: Please add further details to expand on your answer, such as working code or documentation citations.